# Install Tomcat on Linux server

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, glassfish

I am trying to install Tomcat on my linux server .Once I had installed glassfish and already working with it . I successfully installed tomcat7 to my server but when I request the machine url : 8081 (I edited the port number becouse of multiple tomcat and glassfish) default  tomcat page not working and  therefore I see inside of   catalina.out file a content `/usr/lib/server/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/bin/catalina.sh: line 389: /usr/local/jdk/bin/java: No such file or directory`

I m not good at this setup enviroment part.But As I understood it says i m looking for java on this path `"/usr/local/jdk/bin/java"` and cant find java .After that when I check my tomcat path with which-java   it returns `/usr/bin/java/`   but this java is a link file type whatever not the java I looked for or i can use .

Here is link `[java.file]http://balabanhafriyat.com/java.File` 
Now I want to learn   what is the solution for this solution if I change java directory can it   effect glassfish ?if yes how I can edit java path info for  tomcat and glassfish ?
Lastly all the tutorials writers says set java home `/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_07/bin/java`  but I have no path like this i can create it but is it true ?

Thanks for all advice , critic and help.

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you using?  Did you install tomcat with the package manager of your distribution?  If not: Why?

Comment: @AndreasFlorath  My linuux version is 
  LSB Version:    :core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-ia32:core-4.0-     
   noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-ia32:graphics-4.0-  
    noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-ia32:printing-4.0-noarch
    Distributor ID: CentOS
    Description:    CentOS release 5.8 (Final)
    Release:        5.8
    Codename:       Final
    </blink>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently followed this blog's instructions, that I found very helpful, especially regarding all those env vars :

http://diegobenna.blogspot.fr/2011/01/install-tomcat-7-in-ubuntu-1010.html

(it starts with the installation of the JDK, don't hesitate to reinstall it).

Comment: But it gives error when i try to  shutdown it 
   /usr/local/jdk/bin/java: No such file or directory
it try to use older java but i had set it many times as 
   /usr/local/jdk/
how can i set  JAVA_HOME=""  permanently 
Thanks